# Which LinkedIn enterprise product should I use to get access to job title (r_basicprofile) permission for v2 API?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I'm migrating my website from V1 to V2 LinkedIn API.
It is clear in the documentation that **r_basicprofile** permission is not available by default in V2. And to get access to it I need to apply for partner program.
But there are no clear explanation (documentation) on these programs.

Which application I'd need to use to get access to:

- **job title**
- birthday
- number of user's connections

Answer (score 0):

To access any of the following full profile fields, your app must request the '**r_fullprofile**' member permission. you will have to apply to become a member of a relevant Partner Program to get this permission.

Comment: Thanks that's clear from the documentation.
But wat is "relevant" Partner Program?
Because there is no proper description for those programs.

Comment: you can look into this link. https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program#get-started